# Sandwich the data cell with 0 value in Python with pandas

Tags: python, database, pandas

My dataset has this format (the first row is header)

```
0   1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
Nan 6    5    8    9    2    Nan  Nan  Nan  Nan  Nan
Nan 3    8    Nan  Nan  Nan  Nan  Nan  Nan  Nan  Nan
Nan 5    9    2    4    Nan  Nan  Nan  Nan  Nan  Nan
```

I want to insert 0 in front and in the back of the cell has data, e.g:

```
0   1    2    3    4    5    2    2    2    2    2
0   6    5    8    9    2    0    Nan  Nan  Nan  Nan
0   3    8    0    Nan  Nan  Nan  Nan  Nan  Nan  Nan
0   5    9    2    4    0    Nan  Nan  Nan  Nan  Nan
```

How can I do so ?
Thank you for your help

Comment: This is rather confusing: index is usually the first column, not row. Is what you posted the content of a text file or else, rather than a `pd.DataFrame`?

Comment: I'm so sorry, the first row is header, not index

Comment: Simply `df[0]=0` will fill the first column with 0s. For the end you need to loop over each row...

Comment: I guess I could use `df.fillna(0)` for filling nan value, but I haven't know how to point to the last column has value yet

Comment: `fillna` will replace *all* `Nan` values. You just have to write 2 line logic to find the corrrect collumn for each row... Try and come back sharing your code if it doesn't work...

Comment: thank you for your advice, I'm trying to do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do this, if your list of values doesn't have a NaN in the middle, is to use `T` and `fillna` with a `limit=2`:

```
df1 = df.replace('Nan',np.nan) #Make sure those Nan are really np.nan
df1.T.fillna(0,limit=2).T
```

Output:

```
   0  1  2  3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10
0  0  6  5  8    9    2    0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  0  3  8  0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  0  5  9  2    4    0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Note:

> I really wanted to use df1.fillna(0, limit=2, axis=1) but fillna is
>   ignoring the `axis` parameter.  Maybe a bug.  I am going to do a
>   little more research.  However T is a good workaround.
>   Edit:  It is a [bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17399).

Comment: Note to self: must remember `limit=2`.

Comment: What happens if the row starts with more than 1 nan?

Comment: Yep, fillna with a value, axis=1 is a [bug](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/17399)

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to check the diffs along axis=1 of `isnull` as integers.  `-1` indicates null to not null while `1` indicates not null to null.

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    [np.nan, np.nan, 1, 2, 3, np.nan, np.nan],
    [np.nan, 4, 5, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
    [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 7, 8, 9, np.nan]
])

df

     0    1    2    3    4    5    6
0  NaN  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  0.0  NaN
1  0.0  4.0  5.0  0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  0.0  7.0  8.0  9.0  0.0
```

Then

```
v = df.values

d = np.diff(df.isnull().values.astype(int), axis=1)

i0, j0 = np.where(d == -1)
i1, j1 = np.where(d == 1)

v[i0, j0] = 0
v[i1, j1 + 1] = 0

pd.DataFrame(v, df.index, df.columns)

     0    1    2    3    4    5    6
0  NaN  0.0  1.0  2.0  3.0  0.0  NaN
1  0.0  4.0  5.0  0.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  0.0  7.0  8.0  9.0  0.0
```

Notice that we correctly identify where to place the zeros even when `np.nan` starts at other locations other than the second column.

Comment: @ThanhNguyen if your row ever starts with more than one nan, this will still accurately identify where to fill in the appropriate zeros

Comment: @piRSquared Yep, if the values starts with more that one NaN, then he'll have to switch logic.  That fillna limit=2 will not work.